# How can I get all of the text and the Search Bar on the same line?

Tags: html, css

---I tried all of the suggestions on fixing the code, but either the search bar comes before the "More" tab, or just doesn't change the final output. Any further ideas?

Ok I'm trying to re-create the BBC website. In the process when I tried to add the search bar it seemed to wrap my top bar under itself, and I'm not sure how to fix the issue. I'll post the code (about 120 lines, not much) and a link to the reference site and hopefully somebody out there knows how to deal with this.

http://www.bbc.com/news/technology ---- all I'm trying to do at the top bar that will take you to other portions of the website (i.e. the top tabs labelled "News, Sports, Weather,...etc." But like i said the code makes my search bar wrap down.[My code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9iKP.png)

```css
#topbar {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.topbar-section {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  height: 100%;
}
#signin-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  padding-right: 65px;
}
#signin-image {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 9px 15px;
  float: left;
}
.topbar-menu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 10px 14px 0px 14px;
  height: 27px;
}
#more-arrow {
  width: 6px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}
#search-box {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px;
  float: left;
}
#search-icon {
  height: 26px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <img id="logo" src="images/bbc-blocks-dark.png">
  <div id="signin-div" class="topbar-section">
    <img id="signin-image" src="images/signinimage.png">
    <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">News</div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Sport</div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Weather</div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Shop</div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Earth</div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">Travel</div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    More
    <img id="more-arrow" src="images/more-arrow.png">
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    <input id="search-box" type="text" value="Search">
    <input type="image" id="search-icon" src="images/search-icon.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Increase this: `width:800px;`?

Comment: It looks like your elements in your `top-bar` doesn't fit in 800px

Comment: why your `<body>` tag is in `<head>` tag

Comment: easiest way to implement would be to create a UL for the top menu, style it so it is displaying inline (or using list-inline) and simply having the search box within the last li and float it to the right

Comment: also you could look into BBC-s source, like studying it

Comment: try `#topbar { width:1050px;}`

Comment: Why i am feeling that you have created another id for asking the same question which you already asked on site?? Why spamming?

Comment: I have solved it check output in [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/nudezet/edit?html,css)

Answer (score 0):

Increase toolbar with to 1000px and Apply float right on search area.

Here is the updated code

```css
#topbar {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#logo {
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.topbar-section {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  height: 100%;
}
#signin-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  padding-right: 65px;
}
#signin-image {
  width: 25px;
  margin: 9px 15px;
  float: left;
}
.topbar-menu {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding: 10px 14px 0px 14px;
  height: 27px;
}
#more-arrow {
  width: 6px;
  margin-left: 65px;
}
#search-area {
  float: right;
}
#search-box {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px;
  //margin:7px 0px 7px;
  float: left;
}
#search-icon {
  height: 26px;
  // margin-top: 7px;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <img id="logo" src="images/bbc-blocks-dark.png">
  <div id="signin-div" class="topbar-section">
    <img id="signin-image" src="images/signinimage.png">
    <span id="signin-text">Sign in</span>
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    News
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    Sport
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    Weather
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    Shop
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    Earth
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    Travel
  </div>
  <div class="topbar-section topbar-menu">
    More
    <img id="more-arrow" src="images/more-arrow.png" </div
    <div id="search-area">
      <input id="search-box" type="text" value="Search">
      <input type="image" id="search-icon" src="images/search-icon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
```